# What is the max value for HungAppTimeout on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7-x64

To avoid having the windows ghosting effect for one of our applications we want to increase the ghosting timeout to be 5 minutes i.e. the HungAppTimeout value should be 300000. I would like to know if this is with in the bounds of the allowed values for HungAppTimeout registry key?